# How to show all fields of model in admin page?

Tags: django-models, django-admin

[here is the models page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvhDA.png)

In this picture, only the title shows up on here, I used:

```py
def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title;
```

[here is the each individual objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iZtJj.png)

How do I show all these fields?

**How do I show all the fields in each Model page?**

Comment: Do you mean all the child fields from other models?

Comment: @Amirshk I think so? If my model has (username, age, gender, fav_genre, warning), I use "def __unicode__(self): return self.username + self.fav_genre" and this will show me whatver is returned. I want the page to show a "table" of all the fields in column form,, if that makes any sense.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

By default, the admin layout only shows what is returned from  the object's **unicode** function. To display something else you need to create a custom admin form in `app_dir/admin.py`.

See here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display

You need to add an admin form, and setting the `list_display` field.

In your specific example (**admin.py**):

```
class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author', 'price')
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)
```

Comment: According to ``Django`` style guidelines, field names should be lower case. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/#model-style

Comment: The code block which you have specified needs to be added in `admin.py` or `models.py` ?

Comment: In admin @Rakmo

Answer (score 105):

If you want to include all fields without typing all fieldnames, you can use

```py
list_display = BookAdmin._meta.get_all_field_names()
```

The drawback is, the fields are in sorted order.

**Edit:**

This method has been deprecated in Django 1.10 See [Migrating from old API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api) for reference. Following should work instead for `Django >= 1.9` for most cases -

```py
list_display = [field.name for field in Book._meta.get_fields()]
```

Comment: you should pull the field names from the model list_display = Book._meta.get_all_field_names()

Comment: This looks like a better solution to me. Simple, easy and quick.

Comment: It will raise `"BookAdmin" is not defined`.

Comment: Starting from Django 1.10, this wont work. I added an updated answer.

Comment: Will raise `AttributeError ` for `ManyToOneRel`.

Comment: getting `__call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'` when using the second solution

Comment: This will throw an error when it's getting to the related fields of the model (which are often in place in your model), to prevent that issue you could add a simple condition:
`[field.name for field in Book._meta.get_fields()  if not field.is_relation]`

Answer (score 49):

If you want to include all but the ManyToManyField field names, and have them in the same order as in the models.py file, you can use:

```py
list_display = [field.name for field in Book._meta.fields if field.name != "id"]
```

As you can see, I also excluded the id.

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you could create a subclass of ModelAdmin:

```py
class CustomModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    
    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        self.list_display = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields if field.name != "id"]
        super(CustomModelAdmin, self).__init__(model, admin_site)
```

and then just inherit from that:

```py
class BookAdmin(CustomModelAdmin):
    pass
```

or you can do it as a mixin:

```py
class CustomModelAdminMixin(object):

    def __init__(self, model, admin_site):
        self.list_display = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields if field.name != "id"]
        super(CustomModelAdminMixin, self).__init__(model, admin_site)

class TradeAdmin(CustomModelAdminMixin, admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass
```

The mixin is useful if you want to inherit from something other than admin.ModelAdmin.

Comment: Thank you! This is an extremely useful mixin. It is very sub-optimal otherwise needing to manage new/stale/changed model fields in admin.py all the time.

Comment: I like being able to edit on the change list also, and this is easily done with one more line: `self.list_editable = [field.name for field in model._meta.fields if field.editable]`. I exclude fields with `editable=False`. Personally I leave in the `id` field, so tweak your code accordingly.

Comment: Can I do this for all my models by default without writing a dummy BookAdmin class?

Answer (score 18):

I found [OBu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2304092/obu)'s answer here to be very useful for me. He mentions:

> The drawback is, the fields are in sorted order.

A small adjustment to his method solves this problem as well:

```
list_display  = [f.name for f in Book._meta.fields]
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Simple and easy way. Thank you

Comment: which one is documentation for this? I cannot find

Answer (score 17):

The problem with most of these answers is that they will break if your model contains `ManyToManyField` or `ForeignKey` fields.

For the truly lazy, you can do this in your `admin.py`:

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from my_app.models import Model1, Model2, Model3


@admin.register(Model1, Model2, Model3)
class UniversalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def get_list_display(self, request):
        return [field.name for field in self.model._meta.concrete_fields]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just a note for self: if used with import, the code looks like this 
`for model in [Model1, Model2, Model3]: admin.site.register(model, UniversalAdmin)`

Answer (score 9):

Many of the answers are broken by Django 1.10. For version 1.10 or above, this should be

```
list_display = [f.name for f in Book._meta.get_fields()]
```

[Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/meta/#migrating-from-the-old-api)

Comment: getting error `TypeError __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'`. `get_fields()` returns all fields including releted fields. using `model._meta.fields` works but it doesn't cover all fields

Answer (score 5):

Here is my approach, will work with any model class:

```
MySpecialAdmin = lambda model: type('SubClass'+model.__name__, (admin.ModelAdmin,), {
    'list_display': [x.name for x in model._meta.fields],
    'list_select_related': [x.name for x in model._meta.fields if isinstance(x, (ManyToOneRel, ForeignKey, OneToOneField,))]
})
```

This will do two things:

1. Add all fields to model admin
2. Makes sure that there is only a single database call for each related object (instead of one per instance)

Then to register you model:

```
admin.site.register(MyModel, MySpecialAdmin(MyModel))
```

Note: if you are using a different default model admin, replace 'admin.ModelAdmin' with your admin base class

Comment: Please include the imports :)

Answer (score 3):

Show all fields:

```
list_display = [field.attname for field in BookModel._meta.fields]
```

Comment: sorry, my mistake

Answer (score 2):

Every solution found here raises an error like this

`The value of 'list_display[n]' must not be a ManyToManyField.`

If the model contains a `Many to Many` field.

A possible solution that worked for me is:

`list_display = [field.name for field in MyModel._meta.get_fields() if not x.many_to_many]`

Answer (score 1):

I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44328647/615379) and thought I'd post the complete admin.py code (in this case, I wanted all the User model fields to appear in admin)

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models import ManyToOneRel, ForeignKey, OneToOneField


MySpecialAdmin = lambda model: type('SubClass'+model.__name__, (admin.ModelAdmin,), {
    'list_display': [x.name for x in model._meta.fields],
    'list_select_related': [x.name for x in model._meta.fields if isinstance(x, (ManyToOneRel, ForeignKey, OneToOneField,))]
})

admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, MySpecialAdmin(User))
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Django `3.1.4` and here is my solution.

I have a model Qualification

model.py

```
from django.db import models

TRUE_FALSE_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'Yes'),
    (0, 'No')
)


class Qualification(models.Model):
    qual_key = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=20)
    qual_desc = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    is_active = models.IntegerField(choices=TRUE_FALSE_CHOICES)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField()
    created_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField()
    updated_by = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'qualification'
```

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Qualification


@admin.register(Qualification)
class QualificationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [field.name for field in Qualification._meta.fields if field.name not in ('id', 'qual_key', 'qual_desc')]
    list_display.insert(0, '__str__')
```

here i am showing all fields in list_display excluding 'id', 'qual_key', 'qual_desc' and inserting `'__str__'` at the beginning.

This answer is helpful when you have large number of modal fields, though i suggest write all fields one by one for better functionality.

Answer (score 1):

list_display = [field.name for field in Book._meta.get_fields()]

This should work even with python 3.9

happy coding

Comment: in which django version this is working? this solution has also been provided before and it is not working `TypeError __call__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'manager'`

Answer (score 1):

I needed to show all fields for multiple models, I did using the following style:

```
   @admin.register(
        AnalyticsData,
        TechnologyData,
        TradingData,
    )
    class CommonAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
        search_fields = ()
    
        def get_list_display(self, request):
            return [
                field.name 
                for field in self.model._meta.concrete_fields 
                if field.name != "id" and not field.many_to_many
            ]
```

But you can also do this by creating a mixin, if your models have different fields.