# How can i show all fields in admin panel - Django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, django-admin-filters

`models.py`

```py
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField()
```

`Admin.py`

```py
class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [name, location, date_created]

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

Instead of writing write each one field `list_display = [name, location, date_created]`, there is an way to get all fields in admin?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show all fields of model in admin page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543032/how-to-show-all-fields-of-model-in-admin-page)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import *

def getFieldsModel(model):
    return [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields()]

class CompanyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = getFieldsModel(Company)

admin.site.register(Company, CompanyAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this if you have multiple tables related to each other with ForeignKey or ManyToManyField. This method will avoid the "one_to_many" and "many_to_many" the exception

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Author(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    age = models.IntegerField()

class Publisher(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    pages = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    rating = models.FloatField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author)
    publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publisher, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pubdate = models.DateField()

class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    books = models.ManyToManyField(Book)
```

add method in admin.py file

```
def getFieldsModel(model):
    fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields() if field.many_to_many != True and field.one_to_many != True]
    return fields
```

## Eg.

admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Author, Publisher, Book, Store
# Register your models here.

# method to find model's all fields exluding one_to_many and many_to_many to avoide the <SystemCheckError>
def getFieldsModel(model):
    fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields() if field.many_to_many != True and field.one_to_many != True]
    return fields


class AuthorAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = getFieldsModel(Author)
admin.site.register(Author, AuthorAdmin)


class PublisherAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = getFieldsModel(Publisher)
admin.site.register(Publisher, PublisherAdmin)


class BookAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = getFieldsModel(Book)
admin.site.register(Book, BookAdmin)


class StoreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = getFieldsModel(Store)
admin.site.register(Store, StoreAdmin)
```

Answer (score 1):

For search fields you will need a different filter:

```
def get_all_fields(model):
fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields() if field.many_to_many != True and field.one_to_many != True]
return fields

def get_search_fields(model):
    fields = [field.name for field in model._meta.get_fields() if field.related_model == None]
    return fields
```

Then define the model admin like this:

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = get_all_fields(Customer)
    search_fields = get_search_fields(Customer)
```